# Comparing two list boxes based on multiple criteria

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, unique

From selected items in ListBox1 I need to add items to ListBox2.

ListBox1 - populated from "database" worksheet - [Name],[old_number]  //  [Date] taken from Userform Textbox2

Listbox2 - for new bookings- [Name],[Date],[new_number]
[new_number] is taken from Userform Textbox6

-If Listbox1 already has [Name],[Date],[old_number] I would like to update record with msgbox prompt Continue/Skip.

-If ListBox2 already contains [Name] & [Date] will inform user of amendment

-If  Listbox2 doesn't contain [Name] & [Date] and [new_number] will add item to collection.

My Excel hasn't got **`.Items.Contains` function**.

```vb
    Dim iCtr As Long

    'If TextBox6.Value = "" Then  ' check if textbox6 - contract/attendance is empty
    '  ans = MsgBox("Book for is empty. Are you sure?", vbYesNo, "Mr.Rubber")
    '  Select Case ans
    '  Case vbYes
    '  Case vbNo
    '  Exit Sub
    '  End Select
    '  End If

    If ListBox1.Selected(iCtr) Then  ' for each selected item in listbox1

        If ListBox2.ListCount - 1 = -1 Then ' to add first item to listbox2
            a = 1
        Else
            a = ListBox2.ListCount
        End If

        For i = 0 To a - 1

            If ListBox2.List(i, 0) & ListBox2.List(i, 1) = ListBox1.List(iCtr, 0) & TextBox2 Then
                ans = MsgBox("Data already exist. This will amend current data." & vbNewLine & "Do you want to continue?", vbYesNo, "Mr.Rubber")
                Select Case ans
                Case vbYes
                    GoTo carryon
                Case vbNo
                    Exit Sub
                End Select

carryon:
            Else
                .ListBox2.AddItem
                ListBox2.List(i, 0) = ListBox1.List(iCtr, 0)
                ListBox2.List(i, 1) = TextBox2
                ListBox2.List(i, 2) = TextBox6.Value
            End If
        Next i
    End If

Next iCtr
```

If I run the code again Listbox2 data is overwritten by new data.

I want to keep old unique data and add new to Listbox2 collection before adding to worksheet database.

Comment: With your condition, the data should match, if not they will be overwritten, and it seems that you are looking for populated items (so if it is populated, for to the next one). For the first loop you will get: `For i=0 to 0`. Once that you introduce the first data, how the conditional will work?

Comment: First data entry is not much to worry. I can handle it.

My concern is how can I check data in Listbox2 if is compared with new selection.